# Is it OK to only use \n?

Tags: javascript, newline

I have a small webpage that relies on splitting a textarea value by newlines. Is it OK to only use something like `textarea.value.split("\n")` or should I also do something with `"\r"` to make sure it works on all devices? Would it make any difference at all?

Comment: We need more context here. Can you post a larger code snippet?

Comment: If it's only in the context of the web page, it doesn't matter. If that text will appear elsewhere (e.g., you generate a file or something), then it *might* matter. Depends on what will be reading the text. On Windows, a lot of applications are good with understanding that `\r\n` is not the only line ending. But for example Notepad (**not** the ++ variety) doesn't.

Comment: I don't think you need `/r` because browsers normalize the handling of the end of lines within `textarea`s, _I would imagine._

Comment: It's just a webpage, where you input text into a textarea, click a button, and changed text shows up in another textarea. It's really basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your attempt should work. But if you want to implement a splitting with either `\n` or `\r\n`, then try this:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

console.log(textarea.value.split(/\n|\r\n/gi));
```

```html
<textarea>
Hello
How
Are
You
</textarea>
```

Comment: You should split on `\n` or `\r\n`.